# Call Kotlin high-order function from Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Let's say that we have a callback in Kotlin:

```
object Utils {
internal var callback: (() -> Unit)? = null
}
```

And then we call that callback from a Java class :

```
Utils.INSTANCE.setCallback$app_debug(new Function0<Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke() {
            return null;
       }
    });
```

So i have to questions :

1. How can i convert the `Unit` to `void` because i'm forced to return a value ?
2. How can i change the name of the callback setter than `setCallback$app_debug` ?

Answer (score 4):

The Java naming issue is there because Kotlin compiler really generates getters and setters for `var`s. Though it's possible to instruct the compiler to expose the callback as a field - just mark it with `@JvmField` annotation. Java would then treat it just like a regular field.

I also believe if you have to call Kotlin callbacks from Java, you would be better off slightly changing the approach. Instead of declaring the callback as `callback: (() -> Unit)?` I would rather make it `callback: Runnable?`.

It will slightly change the way you set the callback.

```
object Utils {
    @JvmField
    internal var callback: Runnable? = null

    fun main() {
        callback = Runnable { println("Java Runnable") }
    }
}
```

And will significantly improve the way you interact with it from java

```
Utils.callback = (() -> System.out.println("Hello!"));
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Workaround

Depending on your preferences it's possible to implement a workaround which works specifically with java interfaces:

```
// on kotlin side
object Utils {
    internal var callback: (() -> Unit)? = null

    @JvmStatic
    fun setCallback(cb: Runnable) {
        callback = { cb }
    }
}

// on java side

Utils.setCallback(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("42");
    }
});

Utils.setCallback(() -> {
    System.out.println("42");
});
```

#### Side note

You don't need to use `INSTANCE` if symbol is annotated as `@JvmStatic`:

```
// kotlin
object Utils {
    @JvmStatic
    internal var callback: (() -> Unit)? = null
}

// java
Utils.setCallback(...)
```

Comment: `_ -> System.out.println(42)` should have wrong type unless I am missing something; have you tried it?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you're right, just tried and it doesn't work, as expected. Thanks for pointing me out. Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody answered this part:

> How can i change the name of the callback setter than setCallback$app_debug ?

By not using `internal`. Since Java doesn't have `internal` access qualifier, it has to be `public` in JVM bytecode, but the name is changed exactly to prevent "accidentally" calling it. If you do want to keep it internal for Kotlin, you can use `@JvmName`:

```
@get:JvmName("getCallback")
@set:JvmName("setCallback")
internal var callback: (() -> Unit)? = null
```

Answer (score 2):

If a function returns `Unit`, you should return `Unit.INSTANCE`
For different names, try using `@JvmName` annotation or `@JvmField` then you will be able to access this variable as ordinary field rather than auto-generated getter/setter.

Comment: java can't convert implicitly Unit to void ?

Comment: @Garci The Kotlin compiler treats `kotlin.Unit` specially; the Java compiler doesn't.